# RoR Nested Form Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have the following in my org_person.rb model

```
   class OrgPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_and_belongs_to_many :TypRole
        has_and_belongs_to_many :OrgContact
        has_one :OrgCredential, dependent: :destroy
        belongs_to :OrgCompany, foreign_key:"org_company_id"
        belongs_to :TypPosition, foreign_key:"typ_position_id"
        validates :first_name, presence: true
        validates :last_name, presence: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :OrgCredential
    end

    class OrgCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :OrgPerson, foreign_key:"org_person_id"
        validates :user_name, presence: true
        validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
        before_create :create_remember_token
        has_secure_password
    end
```

and in my **org_person_controller.rb**

```
    def new
        @person = OrgPerson.new
    end
```

and in my **new.html.erb**

```
   <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", :class => "form-control" %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", :class => "form-control" %>
          <%= f.fields_for :org_credentials do |oc|%>
                <%= oc.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", :class => "form-control" %>
                <%= oc.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Password Confirmation", :class => "form-control" %>
          <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        </div>
   <% end %>
```

In **shared/error_messages**

```
     <% if @person.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation" class="col-md-12">
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
             The form contains <%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %>.
           </div>
           <ul>
           <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <li>* <%= msg %></li>
           <% end %>
           </ul>
         </div>
     <% end %>
```

Problem is that all fields must be filled out to pass. However, when I submit a empty form, I only get the errors "First name can't be blank" and "Last name can't be blank". The password validation does not show up. If anyone has any insights, please comment. This is driving me insane.

[image: This is what I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of mistakes in your `Models` could be leading to the problem you have.

Your `Models` setup should look like this

```
class OrgPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :typ_roles
  has_and_belongs_to_many :org_contacts
  has_one :org_credential, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :org_company, foreign_key:"org_company_id"
  belongs_to :typ_position, foreign_key:"typ_position_id"
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for: org_credential #this is much important
end

class OrgCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :org_person, foreign_key:"org_person_id"
  validates :user_name, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  before_create :create_remember_token
  has_secure_password
end
```

And it is a `has_one org_credential` relation with the `org_person`,so this line in your `new.html.erb`

```
<%= f.fields_for :org_credentials do |oc|%>
```

should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :org_credential do |oc|%>
```

You should take a look at these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)** for setting up the `model associations` correctly.

Comment: Thank you! You sir/ma'am are a god/goddess among men. The thing that tripped me up was the naming conventions that rails follows. It didn't make sense to me before, but now it does.